# Variable and method checking in Vue

Tags: vuejs2

One of the canonical examples on Vue website is:

```
<div id="app-5">
   <p>{{ message }}</p>
   <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
</div>

var app5 = new Vue({
el: '#app-5',
data: {
  message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
},
methods: {
reverseMessage: function () {
  this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
  }
 }
})
```

My problem is that if I rename the *reverseMessage* function, there is no error at compile time to notify me about this. Is there a way to receive an error at compile time when this happens?

Just a side note, although not really relevant: I am using Vue in conjunction with Typescript.

Thank you!

Comment: It will warn you https://jsfiddle.net/53sh3usn/. You'll need to add additional information on how you're compiling your script.

Comment: I would prefer to have it integrated with the build process that I already have in place.

Comment: Then you’ll need to describe your build process

Comment: Good point: I use webpack. I have the scripts in Typescript.